# C++ Server - To Thread or not to Thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm working on a game server, written in C++, and I'm trying to decide how many threads to use and what tasks to thread. The basic server skeleton consists of keyboard I/O and output to a console, accepting incoming connects, sending outgoing connects, and doing the game "stuff".

What I'd like to know is which things should be given a separate thread. Should each connect have its own thread? I know this is variable, it depends on the project or so, but I would like it to support a pretty decent number of players (somewhere in the hundreds if possible).

Comment: I think the Source engine is completely monothreaded.

Comment: Threading concurrency is hard to "get right". Unless it's *required* for the problem I would urge a simple "event driven" approaches .. even better is to use someone else's vetted library for the plumbing infrastructure, if possible :)

Comment: Single-threaded I/O multiplexing (as with epoll or kqueue) can be very efficient when done right, and may be conceptually a lot simpler than a multi-threaded solution. At the same time, it offers a natural departure point towards multi-threading, since the main multiplexing wait loop can be run multiple times concurrently.

Answer (score 3):

The standard answer should always be: Try it the simplest way first, and only look for ways to improve performance if the simple way isn't good enough. However, re-architecting a large C++ program can be a painful experience, so some guesses about performance in advance may be appropriate.

Theoretically, hundreds of threads are probably OK on modern machines. The NPTL implementation for Linux was tested with tens of thousands of threads, as I recall. If that's the easiest way for you to implement, it may be the right answer.

However, high-performance web servers and similar typically use event-driven models instead. Consider a library like [libevent](http://libevent.org/). I'm sure there are C++ libraries for the same purpose.

I personally believe that languages without first-class continuations, or at least coroutines, are poor choices for this kind of work, but the C language family is how we get work done today, so off we go. :-)

Comment: @paddy, thanks, I give that advice a lot. I should set up a keyboard shortcut for it. ;-)

Comment: You almost could, but it wouldn't be as good without your comment about re-architecting a large program.  There's usually a happy medium of a simple but extensible approach that considers important factors as well as potential future directions.

Answer (score 1):

A good solution could be to use a  [Thread pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern).

Idea is to let the main thread dispatch equitably all connexions in a fixed number of threads.
With a good design, you can easily set the number of thread on runtime.

You can find more informations [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem).

---

Create more threads than you have CPU cores is not productive, and adding too threads decrease performances due to time taken for switching between threads.
By example, for compiling a large project (it's not exactly the same thing, but it's valid for both case), it's often recommended to use no more thread than number of CPU cores + 1.

Answer (score 0):

A very common technique is to have the game server run on one thread to monitor several connections (i.e. sockets) by using a select on each socket. When data is available, grab the data and enqueue it in a producer/consumer type model for the game engine to pick up.

This is by no means the be-all-end-all implementation, but it should be enough to get you started. Sounds like a cool project. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you setup the connections and utilize them in a manner that cause the thread to block waiting on IO then you should be able to service all of the connections and the keyboard on one thread.  You may not want to put the console output on that same thread, as I've seen cases (on windows at least), where the speed of writing to the console is actually a bottleneck (i.e. if the console window is minimized the process runs considerably faster).

If the work of your game engine parallelizes well then you probably want to set use as many threads as there are CPUs less one (for the OS and the other two threads).  If you expect the client to run on the same machine the server will want to detect that and scale back the number of threads it uses.